# Laravel Select where status equals

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have 2 models

1. **Patient** model with `id`, `name`, `address`
2. **Appointment** model with `id`, `patient_id`, `appointment_date`, `status`

`Patient` model has many `Appointments`.

I want to list Patients where patient's previous Appointment `status='closed'` only. Beacause I dont want to add new appointment to a patient whose appointment status is `open`

How can I achieve this with eloquent  ?

Comment: ``Patient::whereNotIn('id', function($query){ return $query->where('status', 'open'); })->get();`` this returns list of patients that does not have any open status

Comment: @Sumitkumar '`SELECT * FROM patients WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT * WHERE status = 'open')`' <-- this is what error I got. It nowhere mentioned Appointment table. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

you can query the patients with the desired condition using Eloquent:

```
use App\Models\Patient;

$patients = Patient::whereHas('appointments', function ($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'closed');
})->get();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. It is working. But here I cannot list all patients who have 0 record in appointments. It is searching only in Appointments where patient has atleast 1 appointment

Comment: if you want to include patients who have 0 records in appointments, i thinks left join will work instead of regular join. The query will be like this : `$patients = Patient::leftJoin('appointments', 'patients.id', '=', 'appointments.patient_id')->where('appointments.status', 'closed')->orWhereNull('appointments.id')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

Use whereNotIn for excluding only the id's that have status `open` and return all the patients:

```
$Patients = Patient::whereNotIn('id', function($query){
        return $query->select('patient_id')->distinct('patient_id')->from('appointments')->where('status', '=', 'open');
    })->get();
```

This eloquent query is same as in sql :

```
select * from `patients` where `id` not in (select distinct `patient_id` from `appointments` where `status` = 'open')
```